# MySQL - Returns wrong rows with appropriate value of notice_date

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

Problem to get the required table from the given table in my database.
Current Table-

```
Gentle_R4   2017-11-14  Company 1   46000.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-03  Company 2   45310.00
Gentle_R2_1 2017-10-22  Company 2   34500.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-03  Company 3   48000.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 4   14000.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 5   50600.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 6   2900.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 7   67900.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 8   36000.00
Gentle_R2   2017-10-19  Company 8   36000.00
```

Need the table like-

```
Gentle_R4   2017-11-14  Company 1   46000.00
Gentle_R2_1 2017-10-22  Company 2   34500.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-03  Company 3   48000.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 4   14000.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 5   50600.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 6   2900.00
Gentle_R0   2017-10-11  Company 7   67900.00
Gentle_R2   2017-10-19  Company 8   36000.00
```

I need to get the rows that contain the maximum date also for the group by company.

I tried:

> SELECT  `notice_type` ,  MAX(`notice_date`) notice_date,  `company`, `total_amount`
>   FROM `my_table` GROUP BY `company` ORDER BY `notice_date` DESC

But get the wrong values of

Comment: Also relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: Thanks... Actually i did't find any perfect solution. Now i can try.